# Infer HList type when building the list with a macro

Tags: scala, macros, type-inference, shapeless

I have a method taking an `HList` and using it to build an instance of a class.
I would like to provide some simplified syntax, hiding the explicit cons. So I'd like to go from:

```
MyThingy.describe( 42 :: true :: "string" :: HNil)
```

to

```
MyThingy.describe {
  42
  true
  "string"
}
```

where `MyThingy` is defined like

```
class MyThingy[L <: HList](elems: L)
```

I've made an attempt with this macro

```
def describe[L <: HList](elements: Unit): MyThingy[L] = macro MyThingyMacros.describeImpl[L]
```

and

```
def describeImpl[L <: shapeless.HList : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(elems: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  def concatHList: PartialFunction[Tree, Tree] = {
    case Block(l, _) =>
      val els = l.reduceRight((x, y) => q"shapeless.::($x,$y)")
      q"$els :: shapeless.HNil"
  }

  concatHList.lift(elems) match {
    case None => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "BOOM!")
    case Some(elemsHList) =>
      val tpe = c.typecheck(elemsHList).tpe
      q"new MyThingy[$tpe]($elemsHList)"
  }

}
```

but the typechecker explodes:

> exception during macro expansion:
>   scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: inferred type arguments [Int,Boolean] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [H,T <: shapeless.HList]

Apparently the compiler is trying to infer `[Int, Boolean]` from the block before the macro expansion. I also don't understand why it requires two parameters, where `describe` and `MyThing` only require one.

Is there a way to have type inference driven by the tree produced by the macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to respectfully disagree with Miles a bit here. I personally can't stand auto-tupling, and if you want to use `-Xlint` in your project, the solution in his answer is going to cause a lot of warning noise. I definitely agree that you should avoid macros when there's a viable alternative, but if I had to choose between auto-tupling and a macro in a case where I'm just providing syntactic sugar, I'd go with the macro.

In your case this isn't too hard—there's just a minor error (well, two, really) in your logic. The following will work just fine:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import shapeless._

class MyThingy[L <: HList](val elems: L)

def describeImpl[L <: HList: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(elems: c.Tree) = {
  import c.universe._

  def concatHList: PartialFunction[Tree, Tree] = {
    case Block(statements, last) =>
      statements.foldRight(q"$last :: shapeless.HNil")(
        (h, t) => q"shapeless.::($h, $t)"
      )
  }

  concatHList.lift(elems) match {
    case None => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "BOOM!")
    case Some(elemsHList) =>
      val tpe = c.typecheck(elemsHList).tpe
      q"new MyThingy[$tpe]($elemsHList)"
  }
}

def describe[L <: HList](elems: Any): MyThingy[L] = macro describeImpl[L]
```

Or more concisely:

```
def describeImpl[L <: HList: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(elems: c.Tree) = {
  import c.universe._

  elems match {
    case q"{ ..$elems }" =>
      val hlist = elems.foldRight[c.Tree](q"shapeless.HNil: shapeless.HNil")(
        (h, t) => q"shapeless.::($h, $t)"
      )
      q"new MyThingy($hlist)"
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "BOOM!")
  }
}
```

The biggest issue was just in the reduction—you need to start with the `HNil`, not build up a meaningless intermediate thing and then tack it on. You also need to capture the block's expression, and type it as `Any` instead of `Unit` to avoid value discarding.

(As a side note, I'm a little surprised this works as a whitebox macro, but as of 2.11.2 it does.)

I personally prefer this syntax with commas, though, and that's also pretty easy:

```
def describeImpl[L <: HList: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(elems: c.Tree*) = {
  import c.universe._

  val hlist = elems.foldRight[c.Tree](q"shapeless.HNil: shapeless.HNil")(
    (h, t) => q"shapeless.::($h, $t)"
  )

  q"new MyThingy($hlist)"
}

def describe[L <: HList](elems: Any*): MyThingy[L] = macro describeImpl[L]
```

The usage here is the same as with the product solution, but there's no auto-tupling involved.

Comment: In a choice between macros and auto-tupling I'd say that the latter was the lesser of the two evils by a very large margin ;-)

Comment: Silly me, thanks for catching the two mistakes! I don't have strong opinions on the auto-tupling vs macros matter, so I'll take some more time to decide which solution to use. In the meanwhile, I'm going to accept this answer since it's more directly related to the question. Thank you again to both!

Comment: Travis, could you elaborate a bit more on what surprised you?

Comment: Btw it is necessary to change the signature of describe into `def describe[L <: HList, T](elems: T*): MyThingy[L] = ...` in order to avoid a variation of https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6840.

Comment: Quite a few hygiene problems here. Something else you don't have to worry about in a non-macro solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you can live with a comma separated argument list then you could follow the style used in shapeless's `HList` companion object `apply` method,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> object MyThingy {
     |   def describe[P <: Product, L <: HList](p : P)
     |     (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L]) : L = gen.to(p)
     | }
defined object MyThingy

scala> MyThingy.describe(42, true, "String")
res0: this.Repr = 42 :: true :: String :: HNil

scala> res0.head
res1: Int = 42
```

In general my recommendation is to avoid macros if there is a viable non-macro alternative.

Comment: thanks, that's a nifty trick I didn't consider! Commas are totally fine and I'll gladly drop the macro solution.

Comment: @MilesSabin, just hit a limitation of this approach today, when I needed 23 elements. Lovely scala tuples...